# How to fill a javaScript array using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I've gotta problem with **filling javaScript array using an Ajax request**. here is my code.
Ajax part is working properly.

```
function GetColumns()
{
    var x = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/AreaModel/GetColumns")',
        data: {
            'id': 10, 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            var item = data.list;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
                    var val = item[i];
                    x.push({ field: "row.Col1.comNm", title: " " });
                }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error!");
        }
    });

    var n = $("#secret").val(x);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //x.push({field: "row.Col1.comNm", title: " " });
    }


    return (x);
```

}

I have debugged the function with fire bug. here is the screen shot.
After the end of the ajax function, **x[] become null**. I have no idea what's happens to the data. Please help me..
[image]

Comment: Try `console.log(x)` after ajax call and check the content on console.

Comment: you are returning the `x` variable at the end of the function, but the actual push happens in the success asynchronously, which executes much later, you should return some type of promise that resolves after the actual data has been received

Comment: you can't return `x` from `GetColumns` because it uses a async method to populate x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't return `x` from `GetColumns` because it uses a async method to populate `x`.

The solution is to use a callback mechanism which will invoke a function once the column details are fetched asynchronously.

```
function GetColumns(callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/AreaModel/GetColumns")',
        data: {
            'id': 10,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function (data) {
        debugger;
        var array = $.map(data.list, function (item) {
            return {
                field: "row.Col1.comNm",
                title: " "
            }
        });
        callback(array)
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error!");
    });
}
```

then

```
GetColumns(function(columns){
    //do whatever you want to do with column here
})
```

instead of

```
var columns  = GetColumns();
//do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

`.ajax` is asynchronous, that means the `success` callback will be executed only after you get a successful response, meanwhile `GetColumns` could reach it's end.

If `GetColumns` reaches it's return statement before you get the response, then `x` will be empty.

You shouldn't try to return `x` in `GetColumns` since there's no certainty that you'll get the response in time.

Any processing of the response's data should be confined to the `success` callback.